# Map yarn build output to stage an artifact

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, yarnpkg

I'm trying to use an Azure DevOps yarn YAML task to build my site. That step completes. But where does the built code go?

```
##[section]Starting: Yarn   
    Task         : Yarn task
Description  : Executes Yarn
Version      : 2.8.1001
Author       : Geek Learning
Help         : [More Information](https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-yarn/wiki/Yarn) (Version 2.8.1001).

Dear Angular and Ember CLI users, please check our [known issues](https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-yarn/wiki/Known-Issues)
==============================================================================
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
    [command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\npm\prefix\yarn.cmd --production build"
yarn install v1.15.2
    [1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
    info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
    info fsevents@1.2.7: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
    info "fsevents@1.2.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
    [3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > bootstrap@4.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@1.9.1 - 3".
    warning " > bootstrap@4.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.14.7".
    [4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 119.26s.
##[section]Finishing: Yarn



##[section]Starting: Stage Files
    ==============================================================================
    Task         : Copy Files
Description  : Copy files from source folder to target folder using match patterns (The match patterns will only match file paths, not folder paths)
Version      : 2.117.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708389)

##[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: D:\a\1\a\s\build\
##[section]Finishing: Stage Files
```

Here is my YAML

```
task: Yarn@2
inputs:
    ProjectDirectory: './'
Arguments: 'build'
ProductionMode: true

    - task: CopyFiles@2
displayName: 'Stage Files'
inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'D:\_work\1\s\build'
Contents: '**'
TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist'
CleanTargetFolder: true
OverWrite: true
```

I have been playing around with the SourceFolder and having no luck.

Adding a "dir" command seems to show that I am in the root folder for my project, but I do not see a build folder

Comment: Which agent do you use? If is private agent, where is your agent located?

Comment: very new to this. I believe I am using an Azure Pipeline Agent

Comment: We have two type agent in azure devops. One is hosted agent(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#microsoft-hosted-agents ), and the other is private agent(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install). You can configure them in agent pool. And, no matter what the agent is, you can use one predefined variable to get your build file path. I have post my suggestion below. You can try with that. Hope this could help you:-)

Comment: The task was stopped because you called `yarn` like a exec, but it's a batch. So the task was finished too soon (stopped before the next command). You have to call `yarn` command like that: 'call yarn install` and then `call yarn build`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64823226/257470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was that "yarn build" appeared to be working, but it was only installing yarn.

I added a second command to "yarn build" after "yarn --production".

```
- task: Yarn@2
inputs:
    ProjectDirectory: './'
ProductionMode: true

    - task: Yarn@2
inputs:
    ProjectDirectory: './'
Arguments: 'build'

    - script: "dir .."
displayName: 'Run dir'

    - task: CopyFiles@2
displayName: 'Stage Files'
inputs:
    SourceFolder: './build'
Contents: '**'
TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist'
CleanTargetFolder: true
OverWrite: true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
##[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: D:\a\1\a\s\build\
```

According to this message, I think the error caused by that the path of `source folder` are not be specified correctly.

As I mentioned in comments,this value is relevant with your agent local path. Anyway, no matter what the agent is, you can use one same variable to get it: `Build.SourcesDirectory`.

It is a [predefined variable](http://predefined%20variable) which can get the local path on the agent where your source code file are downloaded.

So, my suggestion is: modify your `SourceFolder` value as

```
inputs:
SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

to get your correct build path.

Comment: If I change the SourceFolder for task: CopyFiles@2 to SourceFolder: './build' to SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourceDirectory)', the build fails with "Not found SourceFolder: D:\_work\1\s\$(Build.SourceDirectory)"

Comment: @Hoppe Did you lost the ‘s’ after ‘source’. It’s Build.SourcesDirectory. That does not make sense that could not found it because it’s a environment variable.

Comment: No you lost the 's' after 'source' :) I just edited your answer to add it back. I had copied and pasted your snippet and it was missing. It now works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Hoppe ohh! My fault. Sooory about this. But still glad it works now.